# PostgreSQL: ERROR: column “” does not exist

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

I am trying to to select only those actors with rating over 8.5, however the error comes up saying minrating column does not exist. If I remove the where clause then it works but then I get any rating and not those onl

```
select name, min(rating) as minrating
from actors
where minrating  >8.5
group by name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should be a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT name, MIN(rating) AS minrating
FROM actors
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(rating) > 8.5
```

Note that the column alias you defined cannot be used on the `HAVING` clause, so we need to repeat the `MIN` expression.

Comment: Additional information: Column aliases can be used with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY `clauses. And **cannot** be used with `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses. Source:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-tables-and-column-aliases-when-building-postgresql-query